# Eclipse 4 application/window lifecycle

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp

How to hook application or window lifecycle events? At least I need to handle the moment when the application can be closed and to cancel this attempt if it is necessary.
  I didn't find the possibility to enter the URI for application or windows like URI for parts

Answer (score 1):

For Application lifecycle have a look at [Eclipse 4 RCP Tutorial - Lifecycle Hooks](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html#lifecycle) .

Window lifecycle events are not yet directly accessible, [Bug392903](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=392903) has been filed for this.